# Passing parameter from main.js to server.js to mongodb with fetch and findOneAndDelete

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to pass a parameter from my main.js file to my server.js file to delete a list item in my mongodb collection using findOneAndDelete. To do so I am using express, node.js and mongodb (MongoClient).

The parameter I am passing from main.js to server.js is an object {'pltnum': item}

main.js:

```
 function deleteThis(item) {
  fetch('droneInfo', {
    method: 'delete',
    header: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({
      'pltnum': item
    })
  })
  .then(res => {
    if (res.ok) {return res.json();}
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    window.location.reload(true);
  })
  document.getElementById('gets-item').innerHTML = item;
}
```

I want the findOneAndDelete option to be the item value in my server.js file. I have used req.body.pltnum unsuccessfully.

server.js:

```
app.delete('/droneInfo', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('droneInfo').findOneAndDelete({pltnum: req.body.pltnum},
  (err, result) => {
    if (err) {return res.send(500, err);}
    res.send({message: 'deleted item'})
  })
})
```

What do I need to do to have the server.js accept the item parameter from the main.js and use it to delete this specific item in the mongodb collection?

OR

How do I get {'pltnum': item} in main.js to be passed as {'pltnum': item} in server.js?

Help and recommendations are greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you using any middleware ?

Comment: yes, i'm using express

Comment: express is not a middleware. `body-parser` etc ?

Comment: it says on the express guide that express uses middleware functions to handle request and response objects. i'm using body-parser though, yes. i'm using ejs as the view engine too